# BGA Stuff, unstuff PCB Pad Short

Tags: pcb, bga, rework, artix-series-fpga

I am using Artix 7 FPGA (XC7A200T-2FPG676) BGA package on PCB, after unstuffing of FPGA I want to short two pad P18 and R18 on PCB with each other and then wants to stuff back my FPGA .
Note: P18 and R18 are adjacently placed.

It is possible will it work?
If someone does this successfully could share picture?
Your suggestion regarding this will be highly appreciated Thanks

Comment: I imagine its hard to keep them shorted when doing a proper reflowprocess to put it back. Also, under the BGA seems to be worst place to short them. Either do it *in* the FPGA or elsewhere on the board. Why not ?

Comment: What do you mean by : "do it in the FPGA" ?